# If I use swig do I have to build multiple .so/.dll linked aginst every version of python I would like to support?

Tags: python, python-3.x, swig

I have a C/C++ project in which I am using swig to interface with python. I would like to know if I have to build against every version of python lib to have my script be supported or is there a simpler way. I understand that I can use distutils to build on the user machine but this is not always true. I would like to know how other projects handle this.

Comment: Yes. I recommend though that you create your library with a proper ABI and only build the Python wrapper using the different versions of Python. A version for 2.7 and 3.x should be sufficient.

Comment: So I don't have to build one for 3.4 - 3.6 and so on

Comment: Also is this true for both windows and linux

Comment: Python 3.4, 3.5, etc. are not 100% binary compatible - some struct definitions are changed, but I have managed to use SWIG libraries for both Python 3.4 and 3.5.

Comment: You can read about here about how to constrain the usage of Python 3.x to ensure a stable ABI, https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes, **you do have to build different SWIG wrappers** for each Python version you want to support (3.6, 3.7, 3.8 etc).

Even though there is [Python Stable ABI](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html), as for today (March 2020) this is not possible to use because it's not implemented in SWIG (see [#1613](https://github.com/swig/swig/pull/1613)) yet.

There is a PR in SWIG [#1009](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/1009) open, however it's open for almost three years though.